# DNS query sends NS response for NAPTR query instead of going for SRV and A query

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, nameserver, dns-zone, response-time

I am trying to send dns query with NAPTR+SRV+A query but after NAPTR query it dns send NAPTR response with NS response and with additional records that is SRV and A but I want to send SRV and A query exclusively.

Comment: I am unable to really understand the question. Can you clarify what the question and/or actual goal is as? I think that it would also make it easier if you could show what you sent and received rather than only describing it in words.

Comment: I want dns response like this: 3 10.19.89.10 ? 10.10.10.10 DNS 79 Standard query 0x0000 NAPTR peer.newdns.co
    4  10.10.10.10 ? 10.19.89.10 DNS 135 Standard query response 0x0000 NAPTR peer.newdns.com NAPTR 10 0 s
    5 10.19.89.10 ? 10.10.10.10 DNS 89 Standard query 0x0000 SRV _sip._udp.peer.newdns.com
    6 1.179967663 10.10.10.10 ? 10.19.89.10 DNS Standard query response 0x0000 SRV _sip._udp.peer.newdns.com SRV 40 50 4581 peer.newdns.com SRV 21 50 7888 peer.newdns.com SRV 80 50 4581 peer.newdns.com
    7 10.19.89.10 ? 10.10.10.10 DNS 79 Standard query 0x0100 A peer.newdns.com

Comment: But instead I am getting it like: 1 6927.033493693  10.54.41.42 ? 10.10.10.10 DNS 79 Standard query 0x0000 NAPTR peer.newdns.com
2 6927.034282436 10.10.10.10 ? 10.54.41.42  DNS 291 Standard query response 0x0000 NAPTR peer.newdns.com NAPTR 10 0 s NS indns02.newdns.com A 10.30.40.78 A 10.10.10.10 AAAA fd00:10:6b50:4510::51 SRV 10 50 8090 peer.newdns.com SRV 20 50 8099 peer.newdns.com

Comment: It should ideally go for SRV and A query after dns sends NAPTR response but instead after NAPTR query I am getting NAPTR response along with NS response having additional records i.e SRV and A

Comment: So the question is about why there is additional data in the initial response? Or what is the actual question? Regardless, I would recommend that you edit this additional data into the question (preferably formatted in a readable way).

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to send dns query with NAPTR+SRV+A query

If you mean doing one DNS query for multiple record types at the same time, then no, this is not possible under current DNS specifications.

There have been various works and ideas floating around to do that (specially to be able to get `A` and `AAAA` records together) but nothing emerged as a standard, so you have to do multiple queries, one per record type.

If instead your question is why a query for `NAPTR` returns more than just `NAPTR` records, you may wish to read section "Flags" of https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2915 (which describes NAPTR) as it has the following:

> DNS servers MAY interpret these flags and values and use that
> information to include appropriate SRV and A,AAAA, or A6 records
> in the additional information portion of the DNS packet.  Clients
> are encouraged to check for additional information but are not
> required to do so.

(`A6` being of course today completely deprecated, but that is another story).